# Unable to understand why it gives me: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'blabla' of undefined

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have come across a problem that has been asked here before but I am unable to find what I am doing wrong, or understand the reason, or apply other people's solutions. So please, show a little bit more patience and guide me because I am close to losing my mind.

I am switching from jQuery to JS and I am doing some API/JSON practicing. I have done the usual WeatherMapAPI and RandomUserAPI examples found throughout the net with success, following the code and making small changes here and there. Then I generated some data on my own (based on a test Shopify shop) and tried to crawl the JSON.

Lets say I've got some data like:

```
{
   "totalCollections": 172,
   "totalProducts": 2752,
   "....": ".....",
   "...": "...."
   "..": ".."
   etc
}
```

Then i am doing:

```
function getPaginationData() {

    const paginationEndpoint = '/endpoint-url';         
    fetch(paginationEndpoint)           
    .then(response => { 
       return response.json();  
    })
    .then(data =>{
       console.log(data);
    })
    .then(data =>{
       const asdf = data.totalCollections;  
       console.log(asdf);
     });

    }

 getPaginationData();
```

So I am getting the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalCollections' of undefined".

I've seen various other threads and tried various solutions and I haven't managed either to find a solution or to understand why I am getting this error.  Basically, I've come to the point where my solving skills have completely deteriorated.

Why I am getting this?

~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~_~

*EDIT*
Breakthrough (?)

So i figured out that i have to create an empty object to store all my data after i get the response back. So

```
const paginationObject = {}; //create empty obj
function getPaginationData() {

   const paginationEndpoint = '/endpoint-url';      
   fetch(paginationEndpoint)           
   .then(response => { 
      return response.json();  
   })
   .then(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      //update my new object with the JSON data
      paginationObject.numOfCollections = data.totalCollections;
      paginationObject.numOfProducts = data.totalProducts; 
      .....
      ....
      ...
   })
  .then(function(){
      // i can call a function here, for example:
      doHTML();
   });

}

function doHTML() {      
   document.querySelector('.element').innerHTML = `${paginationObject.numOfCollections}`;
}

getPaginationData();
```

Is this in the right path?

Comment: you probably need to return data from previous .then

Comment: If your going to chain a promise, don't forget to chain the response.  For things like this though, `async / await` makes it more obvious.

Comment: not returning anything, in javascript, is the same thing of returning `undefined`. So it's like the second link in the chain is returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your `console.log(data)` works and you can see your data.

```
.then(data =>{
       console.log(data);
    })
```

If this is the case... you could just do it all under the same `.then()` and void issues with using multiple promises.

```
.then(data =>{
       console.log(data);
       const asdf = data.totalCollections;  
       console.log(asdf);
    })
```

hope this does the trick

Comment: So yes this does the trick but still i dont understand why it doesnt work the other way

Comment: Hey @pete_polivol did you try to add `return data` to the second `.then()` ? i.e.  as you are cascading down promises you would need to keep saying what is the new data to be returned and inserted to the promise. But - if possible using a single promise would be best for you here.